# What to use as logical function other than If in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have below set of data.

```
LLimit  ULimit   Col C 
1          3       a
3          5       b
5         11       c
11        15       d
15        17       e
17        20       f
```

in col D if i enter 3.5 i need result in col E as "b" (corrosponding value to lowerlimit and upper limit). I have used If or statement, However is there a way i can do this using Index, Match or array. I tried and it works absolutely fine with the limit numbers (like 5, 11, 17, 3 etc) but not working with between numbers like 14 (between 11 and 14).
Below is what i used

```
{=INDEX(F5:F10,MATCH(1,(((D5:D10)>=H4)*((E5:E10)>=H4))*1,0))}
```

Was trying to attach workbook, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vlookup as follow:

`=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$C$7,3)`

$A$2:$C$7 is your initial table LLimit  ULimit   Col C
Vlookup will look in the first column for the value <= D2 and return the corresponding value in column 3

**Update**
For non sorted column A your Formula needs a modification:

```
={INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$7<=D2)*($B$2:$B$7>=D2),0),1)}
```

You wrote the same condition >= for both limit

```
{=INDEX($F$5:$F$10,MATCH(1,((($D$5:$D$10)<=H4)*(($E$5:$E$10)>=H4))*1,0))}
```

Comment: I don't think v lookup or any lookup is going to help as lookup returns the match. The input number could be anything

Comment: If you write False in Vlookup it will return the Match if True or nothing it will return the <= Just you have to order the first column (it is sorted smallest to Largest in your example why don't you try it?

Comment: Absolutely working. Thank you for this simple solution. I was trying this on a non sorted column hence perhaps it did not work so i assumed it matches the exact number. Thank you again. The only shortcoming to this solution is sorting of column. The grid that i am preparing is going to be amended by lot of people and i am not sure that everyone will sort the column after adding lower and upper values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Assuming D2=3.5 then

In E2

```
=INDEX(C2:C7,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7<=D2)*(B2:B7>=D2)*(ROW(C2:C7)-ROW(C2)+1)))
```

Edit:
To exclude the lower boundary, try this

```
=INDEX(C2:C7,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7<D2)*(B2:B7>=D2)*(ROW(C2:C7)-ROW(C2)+1)))
```

Comment: It returns `b` for `3.5` but `c` for `3`.

Comment: Thanks Taosique for pointing this out. It was including the lower boundary, I have edited the formula. :)

Comment: @sktneer the solution works perfectly fine. thank you for your time and efforts.